# How can I create a function in Swift that returns a Type which conforms to a protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols

How can I create a function in Swift that returns a Type which conforms to a protocol?

Here is what I'm trying right now, but it obviously won't compile like this.

```
struct RoutingAction {
    enum RoutingActionType{
        case unknown(info: String)
        case requestJoinGame(gameName: String)
        case requestCreateGame(gameName: String)
        case responseJoinGame
        case responseCreateGame

        }

    // Any.Type is the type I want to return, but I want to specify that it will conform to MyProtocol
    func targetType() throws -> Any.Type:MyProtocol {
        switch self.actionType {
        case .responseCreateGame:
            return ResponseCreateGame.self
        case .responseJoinGame:
            return ResponseJoinGame.self
        default:
        throw RoutingError.unhandledRoutingAction(routingActionName:String(describing: self))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why not just return an enum value representing the type of response?

Comment: I need to use the Type to create an object.

Comment: I already have an enum representing the the type of response.  I want to create an instance of the correct type for the corresponding enum value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally prefer returning an instance instead of a type but you can do it that way too. Here's one way to achieve it:

```
protocol MyProtocol:class
{
   init()
}

class ResponseCreateGame:MyProtocol 
{
   required init() {}
}
class ResponseJoinGame:MyProtocol 
{

   required init() {}
}

enum RoutingActionType
{
    case unknown(info: String),
         requestJoinGame(gameName: String),
         requestCreateGame(gameName: String),
         responseJoinGame,
         responseCreateGame



    // Any.Type is the type I want to return, but I want to specify that it will conform to MyProtocol
    var targetType : MyProtocol.Type
    {
        switch self
        {
           case .responseCreateGame:
               return ResponseCreateGame.self as MyProtocol.Type 
           case .responseJoinGame:
               return ResponseJoinGame.self as MyProtocol.Type
           default:
               return ResponseJoinGame.self as MyProtocol.Type
        }
    }

}

let join       = RoutingActionType.responseJoinGame
let objectType = join.targetType
let object     = objectType.init()
```

Note that your protocol will need to impose a required init() to allow creation of instances using the returned type.
Note2: I changed the structure a little to make my test easier but i'm sure you'll be able to adapt this sample to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not want to use simple:

```
func targetType() throws -> MyProtocol
```

?

**EDIT:**

I think you can't. Because if you return Type actually you return an instance of class Class and it can't conform your protocol. This runtime's feature was inherited from objective-c. You can see SwiftObject class.

Comment: This would return an instance that conforms to `MyProtocol` instead of a Type that conforms to `MyProtocol`